# Getting error of undefined method 'valid_password?' with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I get suddenly the below error on my server with Authlogic

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `valid_password?' for #<ProductionHouse:0xb53859cc>):

authlogic (2.1.3) [v] lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:191:in `send'

authlogic (2.1.3) [v] lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:191:in `validate_by_password'

authlogic (2.1.3) [v] lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:72:in `validate'

authlogic (2.1.3) [v] lib/authlogic/session/validation.rb:64:in `valid?'

authlogic (2.1.3) [v] lib/authlogic/session/existence.rb:65:in `save'

app/controllers/user_session_controller.rb:162:in `create'

pdfkit (0.5.1) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
```

Cant get the issue sudden happen? Is there any one knows regarding this then please help?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Please report back if you find a fix.

Comment: Make sure your model is using `acts_as_authentic`...  Have you restarted your application server??

Answer (score 4):

I get this error if I start the web server (in my case Thin) before the database is available (in my case MySQL is not running for example).

I load up the app in my browser and it complains that MySQL is not running, so I start MySQL, return to the app which now loads correctly, but will not let me log in (I get the error described by the OP).

If I now go and restart the web server, and try again, I can log in without error.

Presumably `valid_password?` is a method that is added to the model at boot time, and is dependent on the database being available.